# Unable to resolve module "empty-module.js" error

Tags: ios, react-native, jenkins, xcodebuild

For building an iOS React Native app, I am able to successfully run the following command in a MacOS terminal:

```
xcodebuild archive -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -derivedDataPath build -scheme MyProject -archivePath $PWD/build-artifacts/MyProject.xcarchive -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_STYLE='Automatic' BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE='bitcode'
```

However when invoking the same command via a Jenkins "Execute shell" step, it results in the following error:

```
error Unable to resolve module /Users/mike/git/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/empty-module.js from /Users/mike/git/my-project/_:

None of these files exist:
  * ../my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/empty-module.js(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * ../my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/empty-module.js/index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/mike/git/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:136:15)
    at ModuleResolver._getEmptyModule (/Users/mike/git/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:49:26)
    at ModuleResolver._getFileResolvedModule (/Users/mike/git/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:195:21)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/mike/git/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:132:19)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/mike/git/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/mike/git/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (/Users/mike/git/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at /Users/mike/git/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/mike/git/my-project/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:411:33)

I have ensured that the PATH is set consistently between the system and Jenkins for build tools like node and npm. I would appreciate any input from anyone who has experienced
```

similar issues.